# How do I parse this with JSoup (open to alternatives)

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm relatively new to JSoup .I'm trying to parse html scraped from a website that is  along these lines

```
.....
    <FONT COLOR=#2D8F26 FACE="Arial"><B>Claim:</B></FONT> &nbsp; Photograph shows a Chicago Bears fan holding a crude sign at the <NOBR>2006-07</NOBR> <NOBR>NFC championship</NOBR> game.
    <BR><BR>
    <NOINDEX>
    <FONT COLOR=#2D8F26 FACE="Arial"><B>Status:</B></FONT> &nbsp; <FONT COLOR=#FF0000 FACE="Arial"><B><I>True.</I></B></FONT>
    </NOINDEX>
    <BR><BR>
    <FONT COLOR=#2D8F26 FACE="Arial"><B>Example:</B></FONT> &nbsp; <FONT COLOR=#2D8F26 FACE="Trebuchet MS,Bookman Old Style,Arial"><I>[Collected via e-mail, January 2007]</I></FONT>
    <BR><BR>
    <TABLE WIDTH=400 ALIGN=CENTER BORDER=0 BGCOLOR=#000000><TR><TD BGCOLOR=#EAF2E5>
    <FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE=2">
    <DIV STYLE="text-align: justify; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px">
    The attached photo has been circulating around the Gulf Coast region for a couple of days now (since Saturday's Bears-Saints game). Do you have any word on whether it is authentic or doctored? Was this individual really that tasteless and crude?
    <BR><BR>
    <CENTER>
......
```

I'm looking to generate output along the lines of

```
Claim :Photograph shows a Chicago Bears fan holding a crude sign at the 2006-07 NFC championship game.
Status:True.
Example:The attached photo has been circulating around the Gulf Coast region for a couple of days now (since Saturday's Bears-Saints game). Do you have any word on whether it is authentic or doctored? Was this individual really that tasteless and crude?
```

Upon looking at the JSoup documentation, it shows methods of getting information based on tags. But how can I get the desired output using JSoup? Any samples or alternatives with samples would be appreciated.

Comment: Tell us what have you tried?

Comment: Why the downvote? Did the question ask something wrong?

Comment: @Pureferret: I followed the hint below. I was just looking to see if there was something more convenient to suit my needs

Comment: Down votes on questions aren't for 'posting something wrong' they are  for poor research to discourage people who turn to SO too soon. I think it gets called 'gimmee code'. Anyway, that's not my downvote, but i was tempted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want to to get just text part by stripping out HTML entities.Below should work

```
Jsoup.parse("yoursInputString").text();
```